# is this the correct translation of the english sentence

Tags: translation

死体の沈黙 (Shitai no chinmoku) meaning "silence of the corpses"?
would you translate it differently to japanese?
any help woulda be highly appreciated as my japanese isn't really great :)

Comment: Please read ["We don't do translations or proofreading"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se#799) and consider rewording this question. Specifically, please explain how you got this translation, and why you thought this might not be correct. What's the context?

Comment: i dont need proofreading,i just wanna know can it be used as a natural way to say that sentence,i translated it with the help of my friend,im certain it's grammatically correct and everything,i already did translation just wondering is it fine as i dont live in japan and i can hardly grasp your everyday speech ,and you can't find that in the books.

Comment: So,to make it simple,does it sound weird for a native speaker or not? oh,the meaning should be something alongside of the "living people talk too much, make unnecessary noices,but when they are dead,they don't produce any noises,emphasis is on that silence that a corpse "produces?"" like saying loud as a whistle,therefore the whistle (object) produces loud noise,in my example corpse (object) is silent. also if i wanted an a translation or anything like that,id go to other site that does this. im just interested in a opinion from a native japanese speaker.

Comment: So...you're basically trying to imply "dead men tell no tales" by 死体の沈黙? Or something else? All I can say for now is "It's at least perfectly grammatical, but I don't know what this phrase is actually supposed to mean."

Comment: it's so hard to explain the meaning,it's not like dead men tell no tales,as it implies that the corpse is a snitch or something like that.its more like on the note finding it peculiar how a living being and now a corpse produces no sound,while it was so noisy and lively while it was alive.i hope you can understand the meaning,this is exactly why im asking the help of a japanese native speaker,as i can translate it more or less alone or with some help from my buddy,but what im interested is, does it have the same meaning for a native speaker.

Comment: also is there any sort of reputation system or something like that in here,you already helped me  with 1 question before. i want to give you some sort of a rep or something.

Comment: This site has a reputation system, but now I'd appreciate if you **edit** this question so that it incorporates everything you need. If you already know 死体の沈黙 is grammatical, this is an advanced question which needs a lot of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

死体の沈黙 is at least grammatical, but it *is* a weird and "poetic" expression that makes native speakers wonder what it implies. It may work as a rhetorical book title, song title or such. It's like "Sound of Silence", which is weird but works effectively as a song title.

[死人に口なし](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%AD%BB%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AB%E5%8F%A3%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97) is an idiomatic expression that is often introduced as the Japanese equivalent of "dead men tell no tales." But if I understand correctly, the implications of these two phrases are different. "Dead men tell no tales" implies "it's safe to kill everybody who knows the secret", whereas 死人に口なし implies "it's too late if you want to get information from a dead person." At least in Japanese, 死人に口なし does not imply the dead one is a snitch, so you may use it if it meets your requirement. See also: [What does 死者は何も語らない mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17452/5010)